# Unable to use np.where() on a user function to create a new column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a function for Luhn's algorithm that I want to use with pandas dataframe and **np.where()** to create a new column.

```
def checksum(string):
 try:
    """
    Compute the Luhn checksum for the provided string of digits. Note this
    assumes the check digit is in place.
    """
    digits = list(map(int, string))
    odd_sum = sum(digits[-1::-2])
    even_sum = sum([sum(divmod(2 * d, 10)) for d in digits[-2::-2]])
    return (odd_sum + even_sum) % 10

 except (ValueError,TypeError):
     return 1

def verify(string):
    return (checksum(string) == 0)
```

Using this function below:

```py
df['Invalid_Agent_EID'] = np.where(not(verify(df.AGENT_EID)) & 
                                   (df.AGENT_EID.str.len()==15), True, False)
```

This does not apply the function to each item in the pandas series dataframe(df) and raises a `ValueError` as follows:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I tried the same using `Series.apply()` but fails when the data set is huge due to memory failure.

Is there a way I can use the function inside `np.where()` to have a vectorized implementation of the check?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The apply function works for small datasets. My intended file is around 4GB csv (11 million rows) and i use np.where to add certain conditions before applying the verify function. Basically check the if the length of the ID is 15. In a shortened version of the dataset, the apply worked. Any idea how I can use np.where here?

Comment: My goal is to check the checksum for the ID (using the verify function defined) only if the length of the ID is 15 and output True if the checksum fails, and false otherwise. False also if the length of ID is not 15.

Comment: We're saying the same thing then. Because if you skip some of the IDs, the number of rows of the verifications won't be the same as the those in the rest of the dataframe, so when you assign that result to a new column, pandas will pad it with nan values.

Comment: In any case, writing a new function and using that in `apply()` should do the job, e.g. `def is_invalid_len15(string): return ~verify(string) if len(string) == 15 else np.nan`. However, it still won't work if you don't have enough memory to add a new column. How much memory do you have available and what does `df.shape` and `df.types` tell you? Based on those two you can calculate how much memory the dataframe takes up in memory.

Comment: HI Reti43, I've made my original question clearer now along with the exact error I'm getting. Can you please help?

Comment: That error is because you try to apply `not()` to an array, which won't work. You can either do `~array` or `np.logical_not(array)`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Reti43, code modified to df['Invalid_Agent_EID']= df['AGENT_EID'].apply(verify_new2),with minor changes in the verify() function, and works perfectly! Appreciate it! :-)